# [rosjava] Error using rosrun

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to learn how to use rosjava. I am following the official [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo), however in the second part Creating and Running Talker-Listener I am having some trouble.

When I run:

```
rosrun rosjava_catkin_package_a my_pub_sub_tutorial com.github.rosjava.rosjava_catkin_package_a.my_pub_sub_tutorial.Talker
```

I get the following error:

```
Loading node class: com.github.rosjava.rosjava_catkin_package_a.my_pub_sub_tutorial.Talker
Exception in thread "main" org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: Unable to locate node: com.github.rosjava.rosjava_catkin_package_a.my_pub_sub_tutorial.Talker
        at org.ros.RosRun.main(RosRun.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.rosjava.rosjava_catkin_package_a.my_pub_sub_tutorial.Talker
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.ros.internal.loader.CommandLineLoader.loadClass(CommandLineLoader.java:239)
        at org.ros.RosRun.main(RosRun.java:54)
```

Also, is it necessary to use  `catkin_create_rosjava_project my_pub_sub_tutorial` ? Is it possible to run programs the same way it is done with python? Like just creating a file.py and adding permissions to run?

Ps: I have very little knowledge about java.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305422/%5Brosjava%5D-error-using-rosrun/) by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2018-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @rezenders,

The error is because the class you are trying to execute is not in the classpath.

> Also, is it necessary to use catkin_create_rosjava_project my_pub_sub_tutorial ? Is it possible to run programs the same way it is done with python? Like just creating a file.py and adding permissions to run?

The short answer is no.

Let me explain a bit: every Java program has a fixed entrypoint (aka `main` method) that is the first thing executed. In rosjava you regularly write a ROS node overriding `AbstractNodeMain`, so you need some main method to actually run the node for you. That is provided in [RosRun](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/blob/kinetic/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/RosRun.java) class, which is the standard entrypoint for any rosjava application (look at the project level `build.gradle` file; you should see `mainClassName` declared there). When you execute the command `rosrun [package] [project] [class name]` you are actually calling an executable script generated by Gradle, which runs `RosRun` class (which is part of rosjava), which in turn loads your node to the classpath and executes it. There are some more details around all of this, but as you can guess it's not the same as executing a python script.

Did you follow the steps of the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28Java%29) one by one without skipping anything? You shouldn't encounter any errors there.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-11-21**:
@rezenders did that work for you?

**Comment by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on 2018-12-12**:
It worked, I was making a mistake. Thank you for you explanation!